# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener2 error for testng maven project in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

I have tried adding the TestNG jar files to the project folder removing the testNG dependencies and adding them again
but the issue is not resolved still showing the same error

Comment: Check your classpath and run configuration. Share a project sample if there are no ideas

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the Gradle plugin and are still having this issue, change `allureJavaVersion` in build.gradle to `2.13.2` or higher:

```
allure {
    version = '2.13.2'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = '2.13.2'
}
```

if you are using maven update `allure` with version `2.13.2` or higher

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/pull/422